# Event tracking from Google Analytics not working

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to use google analytics to track custom events, but when I try to hit the page:
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-myUA&cid=1111&t=event&ec=Movement&ea=livingRoom&el=desk

It opens the page like collecting, but in my analytics account, it doesnt show any event....

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to track Google Analytics events using Google Analytics event tracking - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Comment: The problem is that I need to add events within a python program and not with a page...

Comment: What does the code look like that is passing taking the url params and passing it into the custom event?

Comment: It just call urllib2.urlopen(url).close with that url, so in theory if that url fires an event it would fire, even when I try to navigate througth the browser in that url, it shows like it fired the event, but in the analytics account, it doesnt shows

Answer (score 0):

You can implement event tracking using Google Tag Manager where you can create you custom events. The procedure is easy to implement than traditional Java Script code as it does not require developer to implement GTM.
Simply follow the below steps for GTM implementation:
1. Log into Google Tag Manager
2. Select “Tags” from the left-hand side
3. Create a new tag
4. Select Universal Analytics from Tag Type
5. Set your Google Analytics Tracking ID
6. Choose “Event” for the track type
7. Set your Event Category, Action, Label and Value as desired*
8. Set your triggers as required

You can refer [Google Guidelines](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6164470?hl=en) for detailed information.